# Is SharePoint just a Content Management System

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am having argument with someone who says SharePoint is just a CMS but I don't agree, can someone clear the facts plz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saying SharePoint is "just a CMS" is like saying a bank is just a place for savings account.  Yes, you can do that and SharePoint does CMS extremely well, but that is almost literally the tip of the iceberg.  It is capable of everything Benny lists right out of the box but SharePoint is also a development platform that allows almost any functionality to be extended to the very limits of .Net itself.  If that weren't enough, SharePoint also has an array of web services that can be used to in other applications as well.

The simplest way I can think of to summarize it is that it is the collaboration and open communication backbone of almost every company that uses it.

Answer (score 3):

For SharePoint 2001 and even 2003, that might have been true, but since version 2007 and forward - SharePoint is much more than "a CMS". Wikipedia says the following:

> Microsoft SharePoint is a Web application platform developed by Microsoft. First launched in 2001,[3] SharePoint has historically been associated with intranet content management and document management, but recent versions have significantly broader capabilities.
>
> ...
>
> SharePoint can be used to provide **intranet portals, document & file management, collaboration, social networks, extranets, websites, enterprise search, and business intelligence**. It also has **system integration, process integration, and workflow automation capabilities**.

Reference: [Wikipedia: Microsoft SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharePoint)

Answer (score 1):

Not to mention, it's now capable of being entirely a social media system. You can add virtually anything to the environment to let it do what you want it to do.

in my opinion, I love it, SharePoint is great...it's got it's shortcomings, but for the most part it is a very strong and versatile product.